# Refresh HTML page from python input

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

NEW:

It worked without isseus for like 40 mins, then the code itself crashed:
this is the outpud in the console

```
Gradi: 29.0 C  Umidita: 35.0 %
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 22, in <module>
    valori='Gradi: {0:0.1f} C  Umidita: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

what do you advice?

OLD:

I have to refresh an HTML page that is rewritten every time by the Python script to have the latest values. Sometimes it happens that the page refresh but shows a white page, with no data. How can I fix this?

```
import datetime
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time    

a = """<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="">
<head></head>
<body><p>"""
b = """</p></body>
</html>"""        

try:
    while True:
        file = open("logtemperature.txt", "a")
        web = open('temperatura.html', 'w')
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 16) #11 modello 16 pin
        valori = 'Gradi: {0:0.1f} C  Umidita: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
        print (valori)
        file.write("\n" + valori + " " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        web.write(a + "TEMPERATURA INTERNA:" + " " + valori + b)
        time.sleep(1)
        web.close()
        file.close()
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    file.close()
     web.close()
```

Comment: Try putting `web.close()` _before_ `time.sleep(1)`.

Comment: opening the files with [with](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) would propably improve clarity in your code

Comment: @JohnGordon Still happens, but less

Comment: @janbrohl where i should implement it? for all files?

Comment: In most cases using with is better than calling close (did that in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making *really* sure the file never is empty or incomplete when reading from it with another program keep reading below the first code block.

If it is OK for you to *almost* never have an empty or incomplete file you would do

```
import datetime
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time


a="""<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="">
<head></head>
<body><p>"""
b="""</p></body>
</html>"""



while True:
  humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11,16) #11 modello 16 pin
  valori='Gradi: {0:0.1f} C  Umidita: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
  print (valori)
  ls="\n"+valori+" "+str(datetime.datetime.now())
  with open("logtemperature.txt","a") as file:
    file.write(ls)
  ws=a+"TEMPERATURA INTERNA:"+" "+valori+b
  with open('temperatura.html','w') as web:
    web.write(ws)
  time.sleep(2)
```

if you are on Unix/Linux (eg Raspbian), you can make your own quasi-atomic write as [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) is atomic, making sure `temperatura.html` is always complete

```
import os

def atomic_write(filename, bytes):
    shouldnotexist=filename+".deleteme"
    with open(shouldnotexist,"wb") as f:
        f.write(bytes)
    os.rename(shouldnotexist,filename)
```

replacing

```
with open('temperatura.html','w') as web:
        web.write(ws)
```

with

```
atomic_write('temperatura.html', ws)
```

On Windows it propably is more complicated...

Edit:

To mitigate your ValueError-problem, you can replace

```
valori='Gradi: {0:0.1f} C  Umidita: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

with

```
try:
    valori='Gradi: {0:0.1f} C  Umidita: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
except ValueError:
    valori='Gradi: {0} C  Umidita: {1} % (something saying there was a problem)'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work without issues for now (i used the atomic write version), i already changed my other codes with it, i hope it will reduce my longterm issues. If you have time please help me on this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682082/password-verification-works-only-for-one-correct-password-i-need-for-more

Comment: It worked without isseus for like 40 mins, then the code itself crashed:
Gradi: 29.0 C  Umidita: 35.0 %
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 22, in <module>
    valori='Gradi: {0:0.1f} C  Umidita: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: For some reason temperature or humidity was a string and not a number (float) as required for formatting with f - thats what the exception  actually says. So it was ok for the first 40 minutes and then changed - this normally shouldnt happen as the [docstring](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/Adafruit_DHT/common.py) says Adafruit_DHT.read_retry either returns two floats or (None, None).

Comment: Already done, but i have less than 15 rep, so can't show it. I there any way to preventi it? or to restart the script immediatly after it crashes?

Comment: Perfect, thanks, now it handle the error, i'll show the full project soon to the community

B Gradi: 29.0 C  Umidita: 38.0 %
A Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 40.0 %
0
B Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 38.0 %
A Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 40.0 %
1
B Gradi: 29.0 C  Umidita: 39.0 %
A Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 40.0 %
0
B Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 38.0 %
A Gradi: None C  Umidita: None % (something saying there was a problem)
0
B Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 41.0 %
A Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 40.0 %
1
B Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 39.0 %
A Gradi: 28.0 C  Umidita: 40.0 %

Comment: @FrancescoRubino in the code i meant you should put something saying there was a problem in italian (?) in the place of `something saying there was a problem`

Comment: ahahah i left it this way, i don't really care of the text error, i get the english one too, i use italian only since the final user will be my grandma. Anyway, i was thinking about making it as a medium value of the last 10 calls in the html file, but i can't understand how to save for a few seconds the last 10 variables, go you have any idea?